# Navigation UL in IE 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have created a website that I have almost completed and tested it in Firefox, chrome, safari, opera and IE 9 and they all work and look the same.

I used Adobe's Browser Lab to test the site on IE8 and IE7 and some of the CSS3 is broken which was bound to happen as it's not supported, however, my navigation seems to break and I cannot figure out why as to my knowledge I am using CSS2 declarations for it.

To see my navigation working here is a link to the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6SkkP/

or here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
<!--Start Navigation Section -->
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/gl/images/logo.png" width=245 height=64 alt="Goldie Locks Logo" /></a> 
        <nav>
            <ul id="main_nav">
                <li><a href="index.html" id="index">home<p> a warm welcome</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="hair.html" id="hair">hair<p>hair extensions</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="beauty.html" id="beauty">beauty<p>beauty treatments</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php" id="contact">contact<p>drop me a line</p></a></li>     
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </div>​
```

and my CSS:

```
header {
width: 910px;
height: 85px;
}

header img {
margin: 24px 0px 0px 0px;
}

nav {
height: 85px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
}

nav ul#main_nav {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
width: 132px;
height: 85px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li a {
display: block; 
width: 132px;
height: 30px;
color: #b06e28;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 55px 0px 0px;  
}

nav li a p {
font-style: italic;
font-size: 14px;
color: #858585;
text-transform: lowercase;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

a#index {
background-image: url(http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/gl/images/index_nav.png);
}

a#hair {
background-image: url(http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/gl/images/hair_nav.png);
}

a#beauty {
background-image: url(http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/gl/images/beauty_nav.png);
}

a#contact {
background-image: url(http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/gl/images/contact_nav.png);
}

ul#main_nav li a:hover {
color: #4c4c4e;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
background-position: 0;
}

body.index ul#main_nav li a#index {
background-position: 0;
}

body.hair ul#main_nav li a#hair {
background-position: 0;
}

body.beauty ul#main_nav li a#beauty {
background-position: 0;
}

body.contact ul#main_nav li a#contact {
background-position: 0;
}
```

Here is what my nav SHOULD look like:

[image: Nav OK]

And here is how it renders in IE7:

[image: IE7]

And IE8:

[image: IE8]

Also, I am using the HTML5 shiv

```
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

Can any one shine some light on my situation?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above doesn't work, just don't use the nav tag and just add a # to make it a div. Then put the html in to divs,

```
<div id="nav">
```

etc.

Comment: This did the trick - thanks for that. However, it is strange that the HTML5 shiv didn't make the nav be recognised as an element. Marked as the correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if IE7/8 handle the nav tag. Try adding the shiv to see if that resolves it.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If not, you might need to change nav to be  then update the css for nav to be .nav

Comment: Hi, I am using the Shiv, but for some reason it's just not working, MAYBE browser lab has Javascript turned off?? Wish I had a windows machine to test on! Thanks for the input friend

Comment: Thanks, you can mark this an answer too for people to be aware of the shiv functionality

Answer (score 1):

The above two answers are right I want to add one more thing to that

```
nav li {
display: inline-block;}
```

ie7 doesn't support the `inline-block` property so try

`nav li {display:block; float:left}` or some fall back for ie7

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would use a `div` as container for the navigation instead